# Unable to select drop-down list item on Google's Advance Search page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-rc, browser-automation

**Issue :** 
Unable to select the language from the drop-down list.

**Please help!!**

**Test Steps:**

1. Go to https://www.google.co.in/
2. Click 'Settings' present at bottom right.
3. Now click 'Advance Search'
4. Advance search page will be opened.
5. Click a drop-down whose name is 'any language'.
6. Drop-down list of languages will be opened.
7. Select any language from drop-down list say Hindi.

**Code is as follows:**

```
    public class DropDown_Settings {            
    static String baseURL = "https://google.com";
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fsettl']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='advsl']/a[text()='Advanced 
        search']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#lr_button")).click();               
        WebElement dropDown=driver.findElement(By.id("lr_menu"));
        List<WebElement> options=dropDown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(options.size());
        for(WebElement value:options){
        if(value.getText().equals("Hindi")){
            System.out.println(value.getText());
            value.click();
            break;
        }
    }           
    }
    }
```

Comment: I got it, strange

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Please help!!!!

Comment: I will try my est

Comment: @iamsankalp89 U there ??

Comment: Yes, Strange it is not work

Comment: Problem is that Findelements not working properl

Comment: @iamsankalp89 yes, I read somewhere that it will be handled by javascipt code but I dont know how to use javacript executor. If u have any idea please let me know.

Comment: I used javascriptexecuot too it doesnt work

Comment: Try code it is working in chrome

Comment: Thanks, its working on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine in Chrome, Try this code it is working in both Firefox and chrome

Try this code in Firefox and Chrome:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fsettl']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='advsl']/a[text()='Advanced search']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#lr_button")).click();               
        WebElement dropDown=driver.findElement(By.id("lr_menu"));
        List<WebElement> options=dropDown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(options.size());
        for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){

            String langName=options.get(i).getText();
            if(langName.contains("Hindi"))
            {
                options.get(i).click();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working in FF but works in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='fsettl']")).click();
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='advsl']//a")).click();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='lr_button']")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='lr_menu']//li[23]")).click();


}
```

Comment: works fine in Chrome,but in Firefox (Nope)..whats the reason?

Comment: I guess, FF has some version specific issue. I was using FF version 47 & selenium version 2.53.1 on which its was not working.

Comment: When I used chrome latest version & selenium version 3.6, it is working fine .